# Problema con menú colapsable

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

tengo el siguiente problema en un sitio que estoy haciendo. Tengo un menú principal que se despliega o minimiza cuando haces clic en el icono de la hamburguesa. Si el menú está expandido no hay problemas pero si lo pongo en minimizado y voy a otra página, el menú vuelve a su estado expandido.

Cómo puedo hacer para que mantenga el estado previamente seleccionado (menú expandido o colapsado) aunque navegue en otras páginas del sitio?

Les comparto el link provisorio donde subí el sitio
http://coutobalbastro.com.ar/admin/index.php

Tengo este script que se repite al final de cada página .php

```
      <!-- Script menu -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.btn-expand-collapse').click(function(e) {
          $('.navbar-primary').toggleClass('collapsed');
      });
  </script>
```

Si necesitan algún dato más me avisan.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que necesitarías una cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para almacenar preferencias del usuario en su navegador.

Cuando haces clic en el botón guardas el valor

```
$('.btn-expand-collapse').click(function(e) {
    var estado = !localStorage.getItem('menu-abierto');
    localStorage.setItem('menu-abierto', estado);
    $('.navbar-primary').toggleClass('collapsed', estado);
});
```

Y cuando cargas la colapsas el menú dependiendo del valor

```
var estado = localStorage.getItem('menu-abierto');
$('.navbar-primary').toggleClass('collapsed', estado);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego, a ver si entiendo reemplazo mi script por el primero que me pasaste y la segunda parte dónde lo pongo? Además tengo que modificar algo en mi código .php?

Comment: La segunda parte es un script que debería ejecutarse cuando cargue la página, ¿dónde pones un script así? probablemente dentro del `$(document).ready(...)` de tu página.

Comment: Esto funciona completamente del lado cliente (navegador), no se necesita modificar nada del lado servidor (PHP).